# Accessing uninitialized atomic private variable in c++

Tags: c++, stdatomic

Supposed I have the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
...
...
void incrementN() {++n_;}
uint64_t getN() {return n_;}

private:
std::atomic<uint64_t> n_;
...
...

};
```

Assume that I initialize all the other variables in the class, except `n_` and that this is not thread local storage, so there is no zero initialization.

I create an object of class A, and keep calling `incrementN()`.

If at some point I want the value of `n_`, and I call `getN()`, can this cause the `load()` routine for the atomic `n_` to crash?

Comment: Do you have an `A` default constructor, or any `A` constructor at all? If you don't have any constructors, or a default constructor (`A() = default;`) then the compiler generated default constructor will call the default constructor of all non-static members ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor)), and the [`std::atomic` default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) will be called.

Comment: Yes, I have a constructor for A, and it initializes the other variables of A but doesn't initialize `n_`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg n_ is default-initialized, object is constructed, it's value is unspecified, so it's not UB.

Comment: Yes, that is true and I understand that undefined behavior by its very nature can allow any weird event to occur. However, is there a specific outline by which I could get a SEGV while trying to access `n_`?

Comment: No, not unless you are attempting to access the value of an instance that has been deleted (or you do something with the value that you've read without checking bounds etc.) You are reading the value of an integer fundamentally...

Comment: I don't think this is any less UB than any other read of an uninitialized value. There's nothing special about atomics in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

The load uses memory_order_seq_cst by default. See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order.

As mentioned in the comments, it shouldn't give you any problems that normal ints won't give. Are you concerned about overflow if the uninitialised initial value is large? See here for possible consequences: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 0):

The n_ member variable is just uninitialized. The accessing of the field will cause a read in memory and  there is no reason to crash, although the layout of that 8 bytes of memory is not known.

The fact that the member is atomic has no importance here. It will cause the compiler not to use any optimization on this specific variable and may also cause a cache line eviction to RAM on every write.